Issues with DualPlanarGraph
Bug introduced in 13.3 or earlier and fixed in 14.1.
I have a following planar graph g:
g = PlanarGraph[{1<->7, 1<->16, 1<->17, 2<->4, 2<->14, 2<->15, 3<->4, 3<->12, 3<->15, 4<->5, 5<->6, 5<->12, 6<->7, 6<->8, 7<->9, 8<->9, 8<->13, 9<->10, 10<->19, 10<->20, 11<->20, 11<->28, 11<->29, 12<->30, 13<->30, 13<->31, 14<->16, 14<->23, 15<->23, 16<->18, 17<->18, 17<->19, 18<->24, 19<->21, 20<->21, 21<->22, 22<->25, 22<->26, 23<->33, 24<->33, 24<->34, 25<->27, 25<->28, 26<->27, 26<->34, 27<->39, 28<->37, 29<->31, 29<->37, 30<->32, 31<->32, 32<->38, 33<->35, 34<->35, 35<->36, 36<->39, 36<->40, 37<->41, 38<->41, 38<->42, 39<->44, 40<->42, 40<->44, 41<->43, 42<->43, 43<->45, 44<->46, 45<->46, 45<->49, 46<->47, 47<->48, 47<->49, 48<->56, 48<->57, 49<->51, 50<->51, 50<->54, 50<->57, 51<->52, 52<->53, 52<->54, 53<->59, 53<->60, 54<->68, 55<->60, 55<->67, 55<->68, 56<->58, 56<->59, 57<->58, 58<->71, 59<->61, 60<->61, 61<->62, 62<->71, 62<->72, 63<->64, 63<->65, 63<->72, 64<->66, 64<->67, 65<->66, 65<->76, 66<->79, 67<->69, 68<->69, 69<->70, 70<->79, 70<->80, 71<->73, 72<->73, 73<->74, 74<->76, 74<->77, 75<->80, 75<->86, 75<->87, 76<->78, 77<->78, 77<->87, 78<->90, 79<->81, 80<->81, 81<->82, 82<->83, 82<->84, 83<->85, 83<->86, 84<->85, 84<->97, 85<->102, 86<->88, 87<->88, 88<->89, 89<->90, 89<->91, 90<->92, 91<->92, 91<->94, 92<->93, 93<->97, 93<->98, 94<->95, 94<->107, 95<->96, 95<->98, 96<->101, 96<->107, 97<->99, 98<->99, 99<->100, 100<->102, 100<->103, 101<->104, 101<->108, 102<->105, 103<->104, 103<->105, 104<->106, 105<->110, 106<->108, 106<->111, 107<->109, 108<->109, 109<->112, 110<->111, 110<->112, 111<->112}]


But DualPlanarGraph[g] fails

Is this a bug? I'm using
14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)


It works as expected in Wolfram Cloud (v14.1.0)

@Domen Oh my goodness!

IGraph/M has planar graph functionality that you can try.

@Szabolcs I really appreciate your Graph/M package and am using it almost every day. Unfortunately I couldn't find a command which produces the dual graph of a given planar graph.

@A.Kato IGDualGraph does this. It can be applied either to a graph (in which case it automatically computes a combinatorial embedding), or a combinatorial embedding. Some graphs have multiple planar embeddings. You can find one using IGPlanarEmbedding (it's what IGDualGraph would use as well). Or if you already set VertexCoordinates in such a way that there are no edge crossings, you can use IGCoordinatesToEmbedding. Note that IGCoordinatesToEmbedding will produce a result even if there are edge crossings, but that results won't be planar (as can be verified with IGPlanarQ).

Interestingly, for the graph in your question, IGPlanarQ@IGCoordinatesToEmbedding[g] gives false. This would mean that the drawing that Mathematica produces is not free of crossings (even though the graph itself is planar). Some of the vertices are so close to each other that I couldn't judge this by eye, and I can't tell where the crossing is.  We can still make a (not very pleasing) crossing-free drawing using IGLayoutPlanar[g], and we can produce the dual using IGDualGraph. The dual is not unique since the graph is not 3-vertex-connected.

@Szabolcs Thank you so much. I learned a lot from your comments; not only for a simple solution to my question, but also how to use combinatorial embeddings.

This looks to me as the same bug as in Is this graph planar?, and it seems that the issue has been fixed in version 14.1.

I've also explained the background of this bug in my answer, and you can use the same trick to get it working also in version 14.0, namely force the GraphLayout to be "PlanarEmbedding":


Alternatively, as suggested by @Szabolcs, you can use IGDualGraph from IGraphM:
IGDualGraph[g, GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"]



Thank you very much for the solution as well as detailed explanation! Since g is already given by PlanarGraph (as opposed to Graph), I thought there is nothing I can do.
